# Using Django Rest Framework, is it possible to get results internally on server within Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a complex DRF ViewSet that supports paging, filtering, sorting, etc. that backends a grid view.  To build an "export" capability, I need to be able to take the same querystring that my endpoint uses, such as:

`?obj_id=129&ordering=latitude&city__icontains=nap`

And be able to, in Django, send that string into DRF somehow and get the fully-modified `queryset` after all the view's filters, sorts, etc are applied (the same way as the GET did).  I could use the fully-rendered json response or some interim filter-applied queryset.  Is it possible to use DRF in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a CSV renderer for your viewset and get that content-type to export the CSV.
There's even [one](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#csv) already available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could, if you already have a `request` object i.e. If you want to use this DRF viewset into another view which has the request object:

```
def another_view(request):

    # make a copy of the `GET` attribute of request object
    request.GET = request.GET.copy()

    # now you can set the query params on this GET object
    # ?obj_id=129&ordering=latitude&city__icontains=nap
    request.GET['obj_id'] = 129
    request.GET['ordering'] = 'latitude'
    request.GET['city__icontains'] = 'nap'

    # you can also set paging options in similar way

    # now instantiate the viewset
    vs = DRFViewset.as_view()

    # call the view for response
    # set kwargs as you need
    response = vs(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # response.data will have what you want here
```